# Comparing date in column x per row and print value of column y

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm relatively new to the python programming language and have set my on little project as a goal to learn python.
Now I'm struggling with two (probably) little problems.
In general I would like to compare birthday dates with the current date.
If the birthday date in column "birthday" = today the name of the person should be printed within a sentence.

The first problem I have is that i need to compare day and month but not the year and I can't figure it out.
The second problem is that I am not able to figure out how I can print the name of the person which birthday is today.
What I tried is to go via the index "first name" but then the whole index will be printed.
Table and code are attached.
Thank you in advance for your help.

| Last Name | First Name | Birthday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Love | David | 07.05.1986 |
| Hate | Robert | 17.12.1976 |
| Peace | Frank | 02.09.2021 |

The last one with birthday 02.09.2021 is just modified to have a true outcome.

Input

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb=load_workbook("U:\\Python\\untitled\\Birthdaylist.xlsx")

ws=wb["Sheet1"]
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(ws.values)
df.columns=df.iloc[[0]].values.tolist()[0]
df=df[1:]
df.head()

for i in df["Birthday"]:
    if i.date()< date.today():
       print("It's no one's birthday today!")
    if i.date() == date.today():
       print("Today is ",(df["First Name"]), "'s birthday")
    if date.today() < i.date() < (date.today()+ timedelta(days=3)):
       print(df["First Name"], "'s birthday is on ", df["Birthday"].date, ".")
```

Output

```
It's no one's birthday today!
It's no one's birthday today!
It's no one's birthday today!
It's no one's birthday today!
It's no one's birthday today!
Today is  1     David
2    Robert
3     Frank
4     Julia
5     Marie
Name: First Name, dtype: object 's birthday
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, compute the birthday for the current year then subtract the current date to get the difference in days:

```
today = pd.Timestamp.today().date()
df['Birthday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Birthday'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
df['When'] = df['Birthday'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(year=today.year))
df['Days'] = df['When'].dt.date.sub(today).dt.days
```

At this point, your dataframe looks like:

```
>>> df
  Last Name First Name   Birthday       When  Days
0      Love      David 1986-09-04 2021-05-07     2
1      Hate     Robert 1976-12-17 2021-12-17   106
2     Peace      Frank 2021-09-02 2021-09-02     0
```

Now you can filter your dataframe:

```
# Birthday today
>>> df.loc[df['Days'] == 0, 'First Name']
2    Frank
Name: First Name, dtype: object

# Birthday in next 3 days
>>> df.loc[df['Days'].between(1, 3), 'First Name']
0    David
Name: First Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it that way and will let you know how it worked.

Comment: Thank you @Corralien this method is also a nice one.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do this in pandas (looks like it according to the tags)?

```
# read file
df = pd.read_excel('Birthdaylist.xlsx')

# ensure datetime
df['Birthday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Birthday'], dayfirst=True)

# set up condition for birthday
today = pd.to_datetime('today', dayfirst=True)
has_birthday = ( df['Birthday'].dt.month.eq(today.month)
                &df['Birthday'].dt.year.eq(today.year)
               )

# slice dataframe
df[has_birthay]
```

output:

```
  Last Name First Name   Birthday
2     Peace      Frank 2021-09-02
```

Printing part:

```
if len(df[has_birthday])>0:
    for _, row in df[has_birthday].iterrows():
        print(f"Today is {row['First Name']}'s birthday") # NB. prints several rows if multiple birthdays
else:
    print("It's no one's birthday today!")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it that way and will let you know how it worked.

Comment: Thank you very much @mozway pd.read_excel does somehow not work. but that was no problem. The rest of the code is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your birthday column is strings rather than date/time, if so you can split it up by the `'.'` charecter into day month and year using `.str.split('.', expand=True)` and converting those columns to inegers.

You can then use datetime to get todays date, and use that in `pandas.loc` to filter on month and day to get who's birthday it is. I've used `.iloc[0]` to get just the string of the name, but if there are more than 1 birthdays on that day, then you're probably better returning a list using `.to_list()` instead and iterate through that to print the names of who's birthday it is today. If no birthdays today, then the Name variable will return empty (i.e. `len(Name) == 0` ).

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'Last Name' : ['Love', 'Hate', 'Peace'],
                   'First Name' : ['David', 'Robert', 'Frank'],
                   'Birthday' : ['07.05.1986', '17.12.1976', '02.09.2021']})

df[['Day', 'Month', 'Year']] = df['Birthday'].str.split('.', expand=True).astype(int)

Today = datetime.datetime.today()

Name = df.loc[(df['Day'] == Today.day) & (df['Month'] == Today.month), 'First Name'].iloc[0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it that way and will let you know how it worked.

Comment: Thank you very much. My birthday column was already in datetime format but thank you very much for the way to solve the issue if the date is a string. I tried it and this also wirked pretty well, thank you

Comment: @Charlotte no worries, be sure to upvote any answers that are useful and accept which ever answer suits your question (from what you've just said, I image one of the other answers that use transformed that column to date_time).